# Android Swap/Edit toolbar on page scroll in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar, android-appbarlayout

How can I set a custom toolbar for each fragment when I am using a `ViewPager`? I want to have different icons when displaying different fragments. I don't want to use `Menu`.

I am using [cheesesquare](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare) as an example app and the activity_main.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_check_black_24dp"
        android:tint="@color/white"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The relevant bit in MainActivity.Java is this, where the ViewPager is set up with different fragments:

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new CheeseListFragment(), "Cheese");
        adapter.addFragment(new AnotherFragment(), "Another");
        adapter.addFragment(new SomeOtherFragment(), "Some Other");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Maybe I can somehow specify a unique Toolbar Layout (which would have ImageButtons displaying the icons for example) for each fragment and set each one somewhere in the fragment java file (e.g. swap them out when different fragment is shown)?

**EDIT:** 
In my other apps what I did was use one toolbar but then hide/show ImageButtons which would display the icons based on what fragment was shown.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbarTitleTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Title"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/clearView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/editButton"
                android:layout_width="48dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:background=
                    "?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:contentDescription="Post"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_mode_edit_24dp"
                android:tint="@color/white"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: do you want the change the tablayout icons when you swpie?

Comment: @VeereshCharantimath No, the ToolBar which is right above it. Where you would normally see menu icons such as the three dots for settings.

Comment: So you want to change the Toolbar every time you swipe?

Comment: @VeereshCharantimath I imagine that is what I have to do.. Take a look at my edit on how I used to do it. I think it is "wrong" tho - feels wrong.

Comment: I think for each fragment in your Viewpager define a Toolbar, so when you switch between fragments you can set in Programatically in the Fragment dynamically

Comment: @VeereshCharantimath I will try that, but wouldn't that make the fragments toolbar inside the viewpager and not above it...?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110869/discussion-between-veeresh-charantimath-and-micror).

Comment: for that remove the Toolbar from the main ViewPager

Answer (score 0):

Use the pageChangeListener with viewPager

sample code is given below:

```
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            if (position == 1) {
                Log.d("Page  1", "Pressed");
                //set Image Button Visibility Gone or visible according to your requirement, tab 1 pressed

            } 
    else if (position == 2) {
                Log.d("Page  2", "Pressed");
                //set Image Button Visibility Gone or visible according to your requirement, tab 1 pressed

            } 
    else {
                Log.d("Other Pages", "Pressed");

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }

    });
```